# Create namespaced XML nodes with dot `.` using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri, xml-namespaces

I'm using Nokogiri to generate XML:

```
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml['nitf'].nitf('xmlns:nitf' => 'bar') {
  // some nodes here

    xml.body {
      xml.head {
        //some nodes here
      }
    }
  }
end
```

The output is

```
<nitf:nitf xmlns:nitf="http://iptc.org/std/NITF/2006-10-18/">
  // some nodes here
  <nitf:body>
    <nitf:head>
      // some nodes here
    </nitf:head>
  </nitf:body>
</nitf:nitf>
```

But I need to have `<nitf:body.head>` instead of `<nitf:head>`. How to achieve such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using `#send`:

```
xml.body {
  xml.send('body.head') {
    ...
  }
}


<nitf:body>
  <nitf:body.head>
  ...
  </nitf:body.head>
</nitf:body>
```